# gnuplot: fetching a variable value from different row/column for calculations

Tags: gnuplot

I want to get a specific value from another row & column to normalize my data. The tricky part is, that this value changes for every data point in my data set.

Here what my data set looks like:

```
64  22370   1   585 1   10
128 47547   1   4681    1   10
256 291761  1   37449   1   10
128 48446   1.019   4681    1   10
256 480937  1.648   37449   1   10
128 7765    0.163   777 0.166   10
256 7164    0.025   1393    0.037   10
128 37078   0.780   4681    1   10
256 334372  1.146   37449   1   10
128 45543   0.958   4681    1   10
128 5579    0.117   649 0.139   10
128 40121   0.844   4529    0.968   10
128 49494   1.041   4681    1   10
# --> here it starts to repeat
64  48788   1   585 1   20
128 110860  1   4681    1   20
256 717797  1   37449   1   20
128 101666  0.917   4681    1   20
......
......
```

This data file contains all points for in total 13 different sets, so I plot it with something like this:

```
plot\
'../logs.dat' every 13::1 u 6:2 title '' with lines lt 3 lc 'black' lw 1,\
'../logs.dat' every 13::3 u 6:2 title '' with lines lt 3 lc 'black' lw 1,\
```

Now I try to normalize my data. The interesting value is respectively the 1st row 2nd column (starting to count at 0) $1:$2 and then adds 13 to the rows for every data point

For example: The first data set I want to plot would be

```
(10:47547/47547)
(20:110860/110860)
...
```

The second plot should be

```
(10:48446/47547)
(20:101666/110860)
...
```

And so on.
In pseudo code I would read something like

```
plot\
'../logs.dat' every 13::1 u 6:($2 / take i:$2 for i = i + 13 ) title '' with lines lt 3 lc 'black' lw 1,\
'../logs.dat' every 13::3 u 6:($2 / take i:$2 for i = i + 13 ) title '' with lines lt 3 lc 'black' lw 1,\
```

I hope I could make clear what I try to archive.
Thank you for any help!

Comment: Gnuplot is a plotting tool, use something else for your data processing and feed the result to gnuplot

Answer (score 2):

If the value you want to use for normalisation is the very first to be plotted, then something like this is possible:

```
plot y0=-1e10, "data" using 1:(y0 == -1e10 ? (y0 = $2, 1) : $2/y0)
```

The normalisation value y0 is initialised to -1e10 on every replot. Check the help for `ternary operator` and `serial evaluation`.

But really you'd better pre-process your data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you want to normalize some of your data in a special way.
For the first plot you want to start from the second line (row-index 1) and divide the value in the column by itself and continue for every 13th row.
So, this is dividing the values of the second column for the following row indices:  `1/1, 14/14, 27/27, ..., (n*13+1)/(n*13+1)`. This is trivial because it will always be 1.

For the second plot you want to start with the value in column 2 from row index 3 and divide it by the value in column2 of row index 1 and repeat this for every 13th row.
i.e. involved rows-indices: `3/1, 16/14, 29/27, ..., (n*13+3)/(n*13+1)`

For the second case, a construct with `every 13` will not work because you need every 13th value **and** every 13th shifted by 2 rows.
So, what you can do:
If you pass by row-index 1 (and every 13th row later), remember the value in column 2 and when you pass by row-index 3, divide this value by the remembered value and plot it, otherwise plot `NaN`. Repeat this for all rows cycled by 13. You can use the pseudocolumn 0 (check `help pseudocolumns`) and the modulo operator (check `help operators binary`).

If you want a continuous line with `lines` or `linespoints` you need to `set datafile missing NaN` because `NaN` values would interrupt the lines (check `help missing`). However, this works only for gnuplot>=5.0.6. For gnuplot 5.0.0 (version at OP's question) you have to use some workaround.

**Script:**

```
### special normalization of data 
reset session

$Data <<EOD
  1    900   3   4   5   10
  2   1000   3   4   5   10
  3   1050   3   4   5   10
  4   1100   3   4   5   10
  5   1150   3   4   5   10
  6   1200   3   4   5   10
  7   1250   3   4   5   10
  8   1300   3   4   5   10
  9   1350   3   4   5   10
 10   1400   3   4   5   10
 11   1450   3   4   5   10
 12   1500   3   4   5   10
 13   1550   3   4   5   10
#
  1   1900   3   4   5   20
  2   2000   3   4   5   20
  3   2050   3   4   5   20
  4   2100   3   4   5   20
  5   2150   3   4   5   20
  6   2200   3   4   5   20
  7   2250   3   4   5   20
  8   2300   3   4   5   20
  9   2350   3   4   5   20
 10   2400   3   4   5   20
 11   2450   3   4   5   20
 12   2500   3   4   5   20
 13   2550   3   4   5   20
#
  1   2900   3   4   5   30
  2   3000   3   4   5   30
  3   3050   3   4   5   30
  4   3100   3   4   5   30
  5   3150   3   4   5   30
  6   3200   3   4   5   30
  7   3250   3   4   5   30
  8   3300   3   4   5   30
  9   3350   3   4   5   30
 10   3400   3   4   5   30
 11   3450   3   4   5   30
 12   3500   3   4   5   30
 13   3550   3   4   5   30
EOD

M = 13          # cycle of your data
set datafile missing NaN     # only for gnuplot>=5.0.6

plot $Data u 6:(1) every M w lp pt 7 lc "red" ti "Normalized 1/1", \
        '' u 6:(int($0)%M==1?y0=$2:0,int($0)%M==3?$2/y0:NaN) w lp pt 7 lc "blue" ti "Normalized 3/1"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]